# Jsoup query, only parse specific elements

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to extract some data (see HTML below). I would like to extract the people who are in HR. only the first and last name.

HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>HR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Paul</td>
        <td>Roberts</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>Legal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Griffin </td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>HR</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What i want extract:

```
Peter Smith
James Griffin
```

what i got so far:

```
public class Extract {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Document Page = Jsoup.connect("URL").get(); //pick up html
        Element List = Page.select("tbody").first();
        Elements Info = List.select("tr");

        for(Element value: Info)
        {
                System.out.println(value.select("td").first()); //first <td> ... </td>
                System.out.println(value.select("td").second() + "\n"); //??? Trying to take the second <td> ... </td>
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting a class on all `td` that has a first name and last name like:

```
<td class="first-name">Peter</td>
<td class="last-name">Smith</td>
<td>35</td>
<td>HR</td>
```

Then calling your JSoup select within the for loop like:

```
Element firstNames= value.select(".first-name");
Element lastNames= value.select(".last-name");
```

Or something along those lines. The point is, select using a class instead would be better and would insure you get nothing but the names.

If you don't control the input then you can also use the selector for:

```
Element firstNames= value.select("td:eq(0)");
Element lastNames= value.select("td:eq(1)");
```

However this requires that you are sure the information is always in the right order.

Comment: The "td:eq(1)" works perfect ty. Do you have any suggestions on just getting the data from people in HR?? Should I just use an if-statement?

Comment: Yeah, I would just use an if(value.select("td:eq(3)").equals("HR"))